# Pig: unable to find an output size reader

Tags: foreach, apache-pig

I have encountered an error while running a pig script like below:

org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats - unable to find an output size reader

Exception while executing (Name: Split - scope-1057 Operator Key: scope-1057): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Error while executing ForEach at [rec1[38,9]]

Has anyone encountered such error? Also this error is showing only when I am trying to store the file through hcatalog. The job runs fine if data is not stored and just dumped.

OS is RHEL 6.4 and Pig version is 0.12 on CDH 5.1

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: Sorry...Cant do that due to legal issues. However, it seems that there is a permission issue. In the MR logs I am getting an error for all failed tasktrackers which basically says that permission is denied to a mapper output file in mapred.local.dir/jobcache/.